# maven tomcat deploy soap webservice error

Tags: java, web-services, maven, tomcat, soap

I am trying to deploy my maven project ws-producer. I have no idea where to start finding the cause of this error. The project is connected to another project called ws-interface by a super pom. I am not sure what I should provide for anyone to able to identify this problem so please feel free to ask for more information.

-ws-producer pom-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nl.hu.fnt.gsos</groupId>
    <artifactId>ws-producer</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>nl.hu.fnt.gsos</groupId>
        <artifactId>ws-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <name>Producer Maven Webapp</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.hu.fnt.gsos</groupId>
            <artifactId>ws-interface</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>ws-producer</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

-ws-interface pom-

```
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nl.hu.fnt.gsos</groupId>
    <artifactId>ws-interface</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Webservice interface project</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>nl.hu.fnt.gsos</groupId>
        <artifactId>ws-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>istack-commons-runtime</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.istack</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>ws-interface</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Needed with JAXP 1.5 -->
                    <vmArgs>
                        <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                    </vmArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>nl.hu.fnt.gsos</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ws-interface</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <file>${basedir}/target/ws-interface.jar</file>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

-super pom-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>nl.hu.fnt.gsos</groupId>
    <artifactId>ws-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Simple parent project for GSOS purpose</name>

    <modules>
        <module>ws-interface</module>
        <module>ws-producer</module>
        <module>ws-consumer</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.8</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>nl.hu.fnt.gsos</groupId>
                <artifactId>ws-interface</artifactId>
                <scope>compile</scope>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>wsimport-from-jdk</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsimport</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <!--wsdls file directory -->
                        <wsdlDirectory>src/main/webapp/wsdl/</wsdlDirectory>
                        <!-- which wsdl file -->
                        <wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlFile>BookService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        </wsdlFiles>
                        <!-- Keep generated files -->
                        <keep>true</keep>
                        <!-- Package name -->
                        <packageName>nl.hu.fnt.gsos.wsinterface</packageName>
                        <!-- generated source files destination -->
                        <!-- <sourceDestDir>target/generated-code/src</sourceDestDir> -->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <server>tomcatappserver</server>
                        <url>http://localhost:5471/manager/text</url>
                        <username>tomcat</username>
                        <password>s3cret</password>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                        <projectNameTemplate>[artifactId]</projectNameTemplate>
                        <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
                        <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
                        <useProjectReferences>true</useProjectReferences>
                        <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
                        <wtpversion>1.5</wtpversion>
                        <!-- wtpdefaultserver>${eclipse.ear.runtime.name}</wtpdefaultserver -->
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>synchronise-eclipse-eclipse</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>eclipse</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <inherited>true</inherited>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>synchronise-eclipse-clean</id>
                            <phase>clean</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>clean</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <inherited>true</inherited>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net2</id>
            <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>codehaus</id>
            <name>Codehaus REPO</name>
            <url>http://repository.codehaus.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>

        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>java.net2</id>
            <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

-sun-jaxws.xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/sun-jaxws.xsd"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">
    <endpoint name="ws-producer" implementation="nl.hu.fnt.gsos.wsproducer.BookServiceImpl"
        url-pattern="/ws-producer" />
</endpoints>
```

-BookServiceImpl.java-

```
package nl.hu.fnt.gsos.wsproducer;

import javax.jws.WebService;

import nl.hu.fnt.gsos.wsinterface.BookRequestType;
import nl.hu.fnt.gsos.wsinterface.BookResponseType;
import nl.hu.fnt.gsos.wsinterface.IBookService;
import nl.hu.fnt.gsos.wsinterface.ObjectFactory;

@WebService( endpointInterface= "nl.hu.fnt.gsos.wsinterface.IBookService")
public class BookServiceImpl implements IBookService {

    @Override
    public BookResponseType getBookByISDNRequestNumber(BookRequestType request) {
        ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
        BookResponseType response = factory.createBookResponseType();
        try{

        } catch (RuntimeException e){

        }
        return response;
    }

}
```

-Error log-

```
22-Feb-2017 21:48:22.618 SEVERE [http-apr-8009-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
 javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/api/JAXBRIContext
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5240)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:666)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/api/JAXBRIContext
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:65)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/api/JAXBRIContext
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:255)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:58)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:521)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:300)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:164)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:577)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:560)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:303)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:131)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 48 more

22-Feb-2017 21:48:22.621 SEVERE [http-apr-8009-exec-45] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/ws-producer] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually error log shows exact problem.

needed class com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext is not in your server or application class path. (it is a transient dependency you have to have in class path).

It resides in jaxb-impl-x.x.x.jar  (x.x.x - is a version as example jaxb-impl-2.2.6.jar)

It depends on what Container you use.

Containers like JBoss have it, but yours does not.

So, you have number of options:
1. Put it in System class path
2. Put it in Server class path
3. Package it with your WAR file.
To do so in your project pom file add dependency like

```
       <dependencies> 
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

*Note.* Not in `<dependencyManagement>` element in "super pom"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this did solve my problem. However you are probably right because I can`t find any dependencies in the generated war librarie folder. So something must be wrong with my pom files in projects ws-interface and ws-producer. I added them to my original post.

Comment: I solved it by editing the dependencies of ws-producer pom from scope provided to compile. Do you have any idea why someone would set it to provided? Again thanks for giving me the right hint, setting me in the right direction.

Comment: There was nothing wrong with your pom. If needed jar file is in class path there is no need to package another one into war file. So, needed scope is `provided`. It is specific to war or ear files. It means during compile time Maven put it into class path, but does not package it. `compile` or `runtime` scope force Maven to package jar file into WAR/EAR. That's it. So as I said very often that jaxb-impl or other implementation is in class path already, so `provided` is the best option.